# Removing rows and columns with NA but retaining the values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a dataframe with 6 columns and 10650 rows. On those file there are either values or NA as shown in the example below:

```
Date         X10   X20   X30   X40    X50    X60
2012-01-01   0.5   0.6   NA    NA     NA     NA
2012-01-02   0.3   0.2   NA    NA     NA     NA
2012-01-03   0.5   0.6   NA    NA     NA     NA
2012-01-04   0.3   0.2   NA    NA     NA     NA
2012-01-05   NA    0.6   0.4   NA     NA     NA
2012-01-06   NA    0.2   1.2   NA     NA     NA
2012-01-07   NA    0.6   1.6   NA     NA     NA
2012-01-08   NA    NA    1.8   2.4    NA     NA
2012-01-09   NA    NA    2.1   3.2    NA     NA
2012-01-10   NA    NA    2.6   3.3    NA     NA
2012-01-11   NA    NA    NA    3.7    5.1    NA
2012-01-12   NA    NA    NA    3.9    5.7    NA
2012-01-13   NA    NA    NA    4.2    5.6    NA
2012-01-14   NA    NA    NA    NA     6.5    2.2
2012-01-15   NA    NA    NA    NA     6.9    2.9
2012-01-16   NA    NA    NA    NA     7.2    4.2
```

Now, I just want to remove NAs  and create 4 columns as shown below:

```
Date         X1    X2    Xmin   
2012-01-01   0.5   0.6   10   
2012-01-02   0.3   0.2   10    
2012-01-03   0.5   0.6   10
2012-01-04   0.3   0.2   10
2012-01-05   0.6   0.4   20
2012-01-06   0.2   1.2   20
2012-01-07   0.6   1.6   20
2012-01-08   1.8   2.4   30
2012-01-09   2.1   3.2   30 
2012-01-10   2.6   3.3   30 
2012-01-11   3.7   5.1   40 
2012-01-12   3.9   5.7   40  
2012-01-13   4.2   5.6   40
2012-01-14   6.5   2.2   50
2012-01-15   6.9   2.9   50
2012-01-16   7.2   4.2   50
```

I tried using help suggested in stackoverflow

```
> final[complete.cases(final), ]

> final <- na.omit(final)
```

None of them worked.

Comment: @akrun From OP's expected result, it seems like the logic for Xmin is the name of the first column without NA values, rather than the name of the column with minimum value? Ditto the last three rows with expected Xmin = 50, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do with `apply`.  Loop over the rows of subset of dataset (withtout the 'Date' column) with `apply` (`MARGIN` = 1), then remove the `NA` elements (`na.omit`), create a `data.frame` with those, and 'Xmin' as the column name of the first non-NA element, `rbind` the elements, and `cbind` with the first column

```
cbind(df1[1], do.call(rbind, apply(df1[-1], 1, 
  function(x) data.frame(setNames(as.list(na.omit(x)),
      c("X1", "X2")), Xmin = sub("^X", "", names(na.omit(x)[1]))))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2012-01-01", "2012-01-02", "2012-01-03", 
"2012-01-04", "2012-01-05", "2012-01-06", "2012-01-07", "2012-01-08", 
"2012-01-09", "2012-01-10", "2012-01-11", "2012-01-12", "2012-01-13", 
"2012-01-14", "2012-01-15", "2012-01-16"), X10 = c(0.5, 0.3, 
0.5, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X20 = c(0.6, 
0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X30 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4, 1.2, 1.6, 1.8, 2.1, 2.6, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X40 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.4, 
3.2, 3.3, 3.7, 3.9, 4.2, NA, NA, NA), X50 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.1, 5.7, 5.6, 6.5, 6.9, 7.2), X60 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.2, 2.9, 4.2
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (kinda) tidyverse-based solution. It does something similar to akrun's answer, and they are comparable performance-wise. The only difference is probably readability, but that's likely a matter of preference:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df[2:ncol(df)] %>% 
    split(df$Date) %>% 
    map_dfr(function(x) {
        cl <- na.omit(t(x))
        Xmin <- rownames(cl)[1] %>% substr(., 2, nchar(.)) %>% as.numeric()
        tibble(X1 = cl[1,], X2 = cl[2,], Xmin = Xmin)
    }
    ) %>% 
    bind_cols(df["Date"], .)

########### OUTPUT ############

# A tibble: 16 x 4
   Date          X1    X2  Xmin
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2012-01-01   0.5   0.6    10
 2 2012-01-02   0.3   0.2    10
 3 2012-01-03   0.5   0.6    10
 4 2012-01-04   0.3   0.2    10
 5 2012-01-05   0.6   0.4    20
 6 2012-01-06   0.2   1.2    20
 7 2012-01-07   0.6   1.6    20
 8 2012-01-08   1.8   2.4    30
 9 2012-01-09   2.1   3.2    30
10 2012-01-10   2.6   3.3    30
11 2012-01-11   3.7   5.1    40
12 2012-01-12   3.9   5.7    40
13 2012-01-13   4.2   5.6    40
14 2012-01-14   6.5   2.2    50
15 2012-01-15   6.9   2.9    50
16 2012-01-16   7.2   4.2    50
```